# Chip 8 Emulator 16 bit memory but only 12 bit memory acces?

Tags: chip-8

I am making a Chip 8 emulator and i ran into a problem.
Chip 8 has 4kb of ram (you normally acces the ram with 16 bit adresses). the jump operation defines where to jump with 12 bits. How are you supposed to set the Instruction Pointer to for example adress 4016?

I'm using this [guide](https://tobiasvl.github.io/blog/write-a-chip-8-emulator/) if I understood something wrong

Thx for helping

Comment: 2^12 is 4096. 12bits is all you need for 4k of memory. A 16bit memory bus is only required if you wanted to address 64k of memory.

Comment: "you normally acces the ram with 16 bit adresses" - no, you don't. You access RAM with as many bits as necessary, will you address 4GB memory with 16 bits?